# dart:mirrors reflectType() not returning TypedefMirror

Tags: dart, typedef, dart-mirrors

I am running the following dart code:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

typedef Func();

void main() {
  final m = reflectType(Func);
  print(m);
}
```

I would expect `m` to be a reference to [TypedefMirror](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.19.2/dart-mirrors/TypedefMirror-class.html) but instead the output is:

```
FunctionTypeMirror on '() -> dynamic'
```

Which is not in line with some [test cases](https://dart.googlesource.com/sdk//+/63fd8f63e66d56f4865445a8bfd836a68fabac0d/tests/lib_2/mirrors/typedef_test.dart?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F#55) that I found on GitHub. I wonder what am I missing? Is there a way to retrieve the name of the original typedef using dart:mirrors?

```
> dart --version
Dart SDK version: 2.19.2 (stable) (Tue Feb 7 18:37:17 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"
```

Comment: It's probably been "fixed" at some point, likely when the VM started using the common front-end. A type alias is not a type. The name `Func` refers to the type `dynamic Function()`. At runtime, there is no way to distinguish a type coming from writing `Func` from one coming from writing `dynamic Function()`, because it's the same type.
Reflection cannot go from the function type back to the (or one among possibly many) ways to write that  function type.

Comment: Thanks @Irn. So I understand that what i am trying to do is not (no longer) possible.